# Java getQueryString

Tags: java, servlets, request, string-parsing

So i'm trying to capture a certian section of a getQueryString(). I know I could try and go through and parse the string to get the certain section I wanted but was hoping to just be able to grab the piece I need.

Here is my query result:

```
N=0&Ntk=General&Ntt=info&Nty=1&D=info&Ntx=mode+matchallpartial&Dx=mode+matchall
```

I'm looking just to capture this part: `Ntt=info`

The `=info` part will change to whatever the search requested was.

I have gone through a lot of the API request function and haven't found anything that works for me.

Am I just going to have to parse it?

Comment: Can't tell what this is.  When you say "query", do you mean "JDBC" and SQL?  Your question needs to be rephrased.  Also, what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`ServletRequest.getParameter`](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.2/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29)

```
req.getParameter('Ntt');
```

It will return null if the parameter isn't set.